# Getting CROS Error even after adding header in node.js for Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to consume REST API from NODE JS  for Angular js,even after adding cors header in my server code I am getting error XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8085/issues. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

I am new to both Angular JS and Node JS.

Node JS Code:

```
 var fs = require('fs'),
http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
 res.writeHead(200, {
     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,    Accept"',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://127.0.0.1:8085',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
    });

fs.readFile('C:\glossary.json', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
  res.writeHead(404);
  res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
  return;
}

 res.writeHead(200);
 res.end(data);
    });
          }).listen(8080);
```

App Code:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['restangular'])
          .config(function(RestangularProvider) {
            RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://127.0.0.1:8085/');
            RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({"Access-Control-Allow-  Origin":"*"});
              });

      app.controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope, Restangular) {
        $scope.issue_id = Restangular.all('issues').getList();
    });
```

Trying to use Restangular  for Rest API Consumption.
Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message spells it out for you.

Your client side code is trying to set an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header:

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({"Access-Control-Allow-  Origin":"*"});
```

Your server side code allows a number of headers, but that isn't one of them:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,    Accept"',
```

---

Remove the line:

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({"Access-Control-Allow-  Origin":"*"});
```

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a **response** header, not a request header.